# Nested Linear Layout,not displaying correctly

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

This is what it should look like 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmEPe.jpg

This is what it looks like on my device https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R3bw.jpg

So the second linear layout on the right is displaying horizontally instead of vertically.It actually seems to display correctly in the preview on android studio according to this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzs2m.jpg

Here is the code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/miwok_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="lutti" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/default_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="one" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: does removing the padding still do the same?

Comment: Removing the padding fixed it thanks!